# Telerik Kendo UI Install from nuget

Tags: c#, telerik, nuget

I'm currently trying to install Kendo UI from NuGet Package. I have already downloaded nuget packege, installed and it works fine on my local VS. But when I commit my changes into github, another user have error to find Telerik package. In the VS i added https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget url and then use my creds for telerik. After this I can download resources from telerik, but my friends cant do this.
Where or how I should add creds on the some config file, and my friends can get branch and telerik restored with my creds? I can change only my local nuget.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik is licensed per developer. So, sharing credentials with other developers is not permitted.

> You must protect your credentials and ensure they are used only by you
>   and not by other developers, according to the license-per-developer
>   policy.

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/installing-the-telerik-controls-from-nuget-package#automated-builds